# Generating userspace events from kernel platform drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, udev

#### Context

A [platform driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772757/1883304) is a device driver written for on-chip components and other devices that are not discoverable. In this case, I'm focusing on the [SNVS power ON/OFF driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/keyboard/snvs_pwrkey.c) for i.MX6 based platforms.

#### Problem

I would like for userland programs to be able to obtain information when the On/Off button is toggled for the platform. I have identified two possible approaches, and eliminated at least one:

1. Register a *character device* as a kernel module that shares the same interrupt as the driver. Allow userland programs to query very `ioctl` and `read/write` operations: **Not possible: The IRQ is not shared**
2. Listen to `uevents` posted by the kernel as it manages devices, and then use a `udev` **rule** to match on the driver and take action. Unfortunately, no `uevent` is posted when the button is pressed. This is simply because the purpose of `uevent` is to output information for when the device is loaded or unload. Being a platform device, this one is loaded immediately at boot and never unloaded. According to my kernel configurator, it is also not removable at all (must be part of the kernel)

---

#### Solution 1

Since I want an event each time the button is pressed via interrupt, I have modified the `snvs_pwrkey.c` driver to generate my own `uevent`. Using [this post](https://www.programmersought.com/article/64838061900/) as a starting point. I have outfitted the driver with the following changes:

```
...

static irqreturn_t imx_snvs_pwrkey_interrupt (int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    ...

    struct platform_device *pdev = dev_id;
    int err = 0;

    ...

    /* Sysfs notify: I chose "change" as the event type */
    err = kobject_uevent(&(pdev->dev.kobj), KOBJ_CHANGE);
    pr_err("%s :: kobject_uevent = %d\n", __FUNCTION__, err);

    return IRQ_HANDLED
}

...
```

I then catch this with the following udev rule:

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/90-local.rules

KERNEL="20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", DRIVER=="snvs_pwrkey", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/sbin/poweroff"
```

Although this *does work*, I do get an exception and stack trace on STDOUT when it fires (but only on the first invocation). This is clearly not desirable, even if it had no discernible impact on performance or stability. More importantly though, I feel like this is an abuse of `uevent`, given I am hijacking a system meant for managing devices on sysfs for sending interrupt notifications to userspace.

With that said, I would like to know if there is a better approach that accomplishes what I have set out to achieve. That being to be able to notify userspace applications when the driver interrupt is fired given that I cannot share the interrupt with my own module.

**PS:** In `/proc/interrupts` I can indeed see the interrupt counter increase if I toggle the button (IRQ 45). However, I'm not aware of any interface I can use to wait or poll for such an event from a user program. Maybe someone else reading this question knows a way to harness that as a solution.

Comment: Check out [uio](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/uio-howto.html) ...

Comment: @MurrayJensen The documentation does not address the case of the interrupt being already handled by an existing platform driver, which is not sharable. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I wasn't thinking too deeply about it, leaving that bit to you ... but my thought was that you might be able to implement approach #1 with uio and somehow pass the interrupts to uio same as you are currently doing with sysfs. Or you could also try checking out the [Linux Input Subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/input/index.html) ...

Comment: @MurrayJensen Ah you mean modify the driver so that it shares the IRQ, then implement my own module? I might give that a try.